# symfony assetic dir. does not exist

Tags: symfony, assetic

I've dumped assets using the folling command:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

I've got a Runtime exception:

> The source file "c:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\projects\symfony\src\LV\IndexBundle/Resources/public/images/" does not exist.

It seems to me strange that:

- the `/` goes to `\Resources` only, after it is `/`
- the directory `images` does exist in `public`
- no CSS work. I even tried internal CSS in `layout.html.twig`. Nothing changes.

OS: Windows 10

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with one of my .less files that no longer exists there, and I'm not calling it anymore from twig, cleared cache and everything but still giving me the runtime exception error. What did you do to fix your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove vendors and re `composer install`, clear cache directory.

If problem isn't solved after that, please share your config.yml here